# How to use CHARACTERISTIC and FEATURE figuratively

Tags: word-meaning, difference

what is difference between these two sentences in terms of meaning and how can I use **characteristic** and **feature** figuratively

> the **characteristics** of modern life has changed a lot.
> the **features** of modern life has changed a lot.

Comment: There's a grammatical error in both sentences.  You have the wrong verb agreement.  characteristics/features (plural) . . .  have (not has) . . .

Comment: Please look these up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

They're very similar, but "characteristic" generally refers to more abstract things than "feature." For example,

> One important characteristic of the coronavirus is that it becomes contagious before symptoms start.

but

> One important feature of the coronavirus is the spike protein it uses to enter cells.

Note that both "characteristic**s**" and "feature**s**" are plural, so you'd use the plural form of the verb:

> The characteristics of modern life **have** changed a lot.

> The features of modern life **have** changed a lot.

"Feature" also has a few special meanings: particularly, a specific function of a device or computer program

> My favorite feature of my new phone is wireless charging.

or in the the plural, to refer to someone's face:

> The actor was known for his handsome features.